Need to order by list using row value using entity framework
I have data in following format as shown in the sample table data. I want to order by this data in ascending order for ND values.
Means like from ND1 to ND10.
I tried the following way:
return await _context.Tablename
                     .Select(r => new ListItem { Value = r.Id, Description = r.Description })
                     .OrderBy(x => x.Description)
                     .ToListAsync();

The problem is: ND10 is appearing in the first position, instead of 1, and it should come at the last position.
Any help on this?



Id
Description




1
ND 1 : Test


2
ND 2 : Test


3
ND 3 : Test


4
ND 3.1 : Test


5
ND 3.2 : Test


6
ND 4 : Test


7
ND 10 : Test




Just use .OrderBy(x => x.Id) ??

I have put Id in this way, but in real db it's different.. so I can't use that

Well - you're sorting strings - so they will be sorted like strings - and for strings, the correct sort order is ND 1, ND 10, ND 2, ND 3 - because those are strings - and not numeric values ...
